# Fix wrong json format javascript or regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, regex

I have json file but that json file have wrong format near **require("./screens/test/test.jsx")** and I need to fix this wrong json format through **javascript**

i have tried one json formatter website which is doing fixing my wrong json format. but I am unable to fix this json format from javascript

you can fix this wrong json through this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
[
  {
    "screenName": "screen1",
    "path": "path1",
    "componentPath": require('./screens/test/test.jsx')
   },
   {
    "screenName": "screen1",
    "path": "path1",
    "componentPath": require('./screens/test/test.jsx')
   }
]
```

What should come from the above is:

```
[
  {
    "screenName": "screen1",
    "path": "path1",
    "componentPath": "require('./screens/test/test.jsx')"
   },
   {
    "screenName": "screen1",
    "path": "path1",
    "componentPath": "require('./screens/test/test.jsx')"
   }
]
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to fix the bad json, or write a javascript function that fixes bad json?

Comment: @DevOfZot I want to write js function that fixes this type of json

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to writing a JSON parser, which is pretty complex.  Your best bet would be to do "JSON.parse(string)" inside a try-catch, and if it catches an error, fix known errors you've seen before with regex.

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare your json as text;
2. Stringify all your requires using replace();
3. Parse you safe json.

```
var json = `
 [
  {
    "screenName": "screen1",
    "path": "path1",
    "componentPath": require('./screens/test/test.jsx')
   },
   {
    "screenName": "screen1",
    "path": "path1",
    "componentPath": require('./screens/test/test.jsx')
   }
 ]
`;

json = json.replace(/require[(]/g, '"require(').replace(/[)]/g, ')"');

json = JSON.parse(json); // your safe json is here
```

Comment: Maycon sometime require comes with double quotes require("./screens/test/test.jsx"). then JSON parse failed

Comment: replace is replacing require globally but I do not want to replace require globally because screenName may have require keyword like this {
  "screenName": "requireDemoGraphic",
  "path": "",
  "componentPath": require("./screens/test/test.jsx")
 }

Comment: Hi @MuhammadNuman. I modified the code (replace line) to work even if "require" word is used in object prop name. Try and see if this works

Comment: However, require("./screens/test/test.jsx") using double quotes also will work! Just try.

Comment: it is not working. it is giving me JSON parse error

Comment: {
    "screenName": "screen1",
    "path": "path1",
    "componentPath": NUMAN
   }. can we fix this ?

Comment: "componentPath": NUMAN. can we fix this because sometime I get Variable instead of require. thanks

Comment: I think that using a var (assuming that can be any name) will be hardest. But, open a new question, showing the new context ("componentPath": NUMAN). I can try to help you again.